# Is there an invalid (dirty) JSON parser for C#?

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON that I have no control over, and need to retrieve it periodically. 80% of the time it's a valid JSON, but not always.

Main issues are:

- Quotes inside values (e.g. `{ "key": "some "invalid" value" }`)
- Objects and arrays that are not closed (e.g. `{ "key": [ "value" }`)
- Empty values, instead of `null` (e.g `{ "key": }`).

I've written a function to fix quotes and empty values, but not-closed-objects are driving me insane.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// 1. Escapes double quotes in json property values
/// 2. Replaces ":," with ":null,"
/// </summary>
public static string TryToFixJson(string invalidJsonStr)
{
    var invalidJson = new StringBuilder(invalidJsonStr);

    string[] stringStart =
    {
        "\":\"",
        "\": \""
    };
    string[] stringEnd =
    {
        "\",",
        "\"}",
        "\"]",
        "\",\""
    };

    foreach (string start in stringStart)
    {
        int lastStartIndex = -1,
            startIndex = invalidJson.IndexOf(start);

        // Fix non-string Json
        if (startIndex > -1)
        {
            string newJson = invalidJson.ToString(0, startIndex);
            newJson = FixNonStringJson(newJson);
            ReplaceStringPart(invalidJson, 0, startIndex, newJson);
        }

        while (startIndex != -1)
        {
            int endIndex = stringEnd
                .Select(end => invalidJson.IndexOf(end, startIndex + start.Length + 1))
                .Where(index => index != -1)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
                .Min();
            if (endIndex == -1)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Fix string
            int innerStringStart = startIndex + start.Length, innerStringLength = endIndex - innerStringStart;
            string newString = invalidJson.ToString(innerStringStart, innerStringLength);
            if (newString.IndexOf('\"') != -1)
            {
                newString = FixJsonString(newString);
                ReplaceStringPart(invalidJson, innerStringStart, innerStringLength, newString);
            }

            lastStartIndex = startIndex;
            startIndex = invalidJson.IndexOf(start, lastStartIndex + 1);

            // Fix non-string Json
            if (startIndex > -1)
            {
                int nonStringLength = startIndex - endIndex;
                string newJson = invalidJson.ToString(endIndex, nonStringLength);
                newJson = FixNonStringJson(newJson);
                ReplaceStringPart(invalidJson, endIndex, nonStringLength, newJson);

                startIndex = invalidJson.IndexOf(start, lastStartIndex + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    return invalidJson.ToString();
}

private static void ReplaceStringPart(StringBuilder stringToModify, int partStart, int partLength, string newString)
{
    stringToModify.Remove(partStart, partLength);
    stringToModify.Insert(partStart, newString);
}

private static string FixNonStringJson(string newJson)
{
    // Remove non-essential data
    string[] nonEssentialCharacters =
    {
        "\r",
        "\n",
        " ",
        "\t"
    };
    newJson = nonEssentialCharacters.Aggregate(newJson, (res, ch) => res.Replace(ch, ""));

    // Add null values instead of empty ones
    string[] noValue = 
    {
        ":,",
        ":]",
        ":}"
    };
    newJson = noValue.Aggregate(newJson, (res, nv) => res.Replace(nv, nv.Insert(1, "null")));

    return newJson;
}

private static string FixJsonString(string newString)
{
    newString = newString.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
    return newString;
}
```

Is there some invalid JSON parser for C#. I've [found one for JS](https://github.com/RyanMarcus/dirty-json). It fixes everything except empty values, but I can handle that already.

EDIT: Some more information to answer comments.

- I'm reaching out to people that produce JSON every time there is an issue, and they fix it in a day or three, but this process is time consuming and requites const attention.
- I don't really know how do they get this JSON, but at this point it seems that it's generated with some string appended that builds JSON string directly. This system is quite old and they won't do anything to make a proper JSON generator.
- Regarding using fixer on JS. This code needs to run inside Xamarin Forms application, I don't think that launching separate Node server just to desalinize some JSON would be an answer here.

Comment: i get what your saying and what not but its really not json is they not confirming to json standards... so i would notify the producer... and ask them to correct it.

Comment: Recommendations for 3rd party libraries are off-topic here.  Though if you can't find one for C#, you may be able to use the JS one.  Create a small Node.js app that you can invoke from the command line to do the job, and invoke it from C# code.  Wouldn't exactly be pretty, but that's to be expected in scenarios like this.  The problem is that the source of the data is broken.  If that can't be fixed, then the alternative is to build something counter-broken to accommodate it.  Now you have two problems.

Comment: As suggested already, I would think your efforts would be better spent trying to get the correct JSON format 100% of the time. IMHO, even if you have some “Dirty JSON” parser that “fixes/interprets” malformed JSON syntax, then how can you be sure your parser is correct? “Fixing” malformed JSON is risky since your code has no way of knowing what the “true” intention was.

Comment: As the saying goes, one fool can generate more invalid output than many wise men can parse (well, more or less). They wouldn't have to fix things "in a day or three" if they just got a library to serialize JSON, of which there almost certainly does exist one for whatever language or framework they're using -- you're better off helping them to find that than trying to find one for yourself. As a bonus, this would relieve them from the burden to maintain code for something they don't fully understand and (apparently) have no incentive to do correctly for themselves.